# Programmatically recreate H2 database schema in SpringBoot application (not while unit testing)?

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have a SpringBoot application with in memory H2 database and Spring Data JPA.
I need to configure a `@Scheduled` job that drops and recreates the schema and loads it with fresh data from a file.

How can I programmatically recreate the schema in my application?

Comment: can you just restart the app ?

Comment: @Antoniossss That's not an option. There cannot be a downtime.

Comment: There will be anyway since DDL is not transactional and you will have to lock db access.
Iv been asking about restart in order to use out-of-the-box `create-drop`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use database version control tool like eg [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) to create and maintain database schema definition as well as initial data. Than, you will be able to easily invoke database migration including drop of whole schema during applicaiton runtime. IT has [some integration with Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app) already.

Keep in mind, that you will have to lock database access in order to execute migration - DDL is not transactional, so database will be of no use anyway during the migration process and you app can yeld many errors during that time.

If locking is not an option - you should be able to create another instance or at least separate schema in running instance, run migration against it and if everything is done, "switch" peristence context to use brand new schema (and probably remove the old one)

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at Liquibase.